# What is it called when someone makes your point for you?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Ok, so what is it called if you are talking to someone and you say

> **you**: I know this will sound mean, but I don’t like talking to most people because they aren’t enough like me (a geek, or weird) to understand what I am saying or get my references.
>   **your friend**: I understand your point.
>   **you**: See!  You just made my point for me!

What is that called when that person does that (in that specific situation, if possible)

Comment: I don't get the example. You say that you don't like people if they're not similar enough to you. Your friend says she understands you. But that doesn't mean she's similar enough to you for you to like her. To make your point, wouldn't your friend have to say something along the lines of "We're exactly alike in how we feel about people"?

Comment: So you think your friend does not really understand you but only thinks she does?

Comment: In any event one often remarks, Case in point.” or “That’s exactly what I’m talking about.”

Comment: @deadrat I also didn't get the example. It will make more sense if the friend says that 'I don't understand you.' That would prove that people don't get what the OP is trying to say, right? Seems like I'm one of those people as the question is not clear to me.

Comment: @deadrat no, it is just an example.  I meant someone makes your point by agreeing to the point.  They made the point you were trying to make just by agreeing to it.  Ugh I dont know how to explain it.  Its one of those if I knew how to explain then I wouldn’t need to post this question type of things.

Comment: If it makes you feel any better, Leah, I understand exactly what you mean.

Comment: You do not make someone's point for them by agreeing with them. You make someone's point for them by acting in a way that illustrates or provides evidence for their assertion. For instance, if you say to your friend, "You're obsessed about your weight" and she says, "No, I'm not. Does this dress make me look fat?", then you can say, "Thanks for making my point for me."

Answer (score 1):

In your example, your friend just ***proved*** your point. (Typically one proves their own point, but it is possible that some external agent can prove your point too - see the example below).

Collins:

> ***[make/prove one's point](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/make-prove-ones-point)***
>   *phrase*
>   If you make your point or prove your point, you prove that something is true, either by arguing about it or by your actions or
>   behaviour.
>
> ⇒ The tie-break proved the point.
>
> COBUILD Advanced English Dictionary. Copyright © HarperCollins
>   Publishers

Answer (score 0):

***You take the words out of my mouth*** — [TFD](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/take+the+words+out+of+mouth)

> to say exactly what someone else is about to say
>   *"I was just going to mention that, but you took the words right out of my mouth."*